# Javascript auto click button every 5 second

Tags: javascript, click, setinterval

I have a html button and i want use setInterval click functions every 5 second. Many times i try but my code not working for this. Please help.
Button

```
<a data-role="button" data-mini="true" class="id-buy-again green ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-mini ui-btn-up-c" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="c"><span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all"><span class="ui-btn-text">Tekrar Satın Al</span></span></a>
```

Click

```
setInterval(function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("a.id-buy-again.green.ui-btn.ui-shadow.ui-btn-corner-all.ui-mini.ui-btn-up-c")[0].click();
}, 5000);
```

Someone can help for this? :(

Answer (score 1):

You would need to change `getElementsByClassName` to `querySelector` since you're passing a CSS selector:

```
setInterval(function() {
  document.querySelector("a.id-buy-again.green.ui-btn.ui-shadow.ui-btn-corner-all.ui-mini.ui-btn-up-c").click();
}, 5000);
```

`querySelector` selects an element using the given CSS selector. `getElementsByClassName` acceps just 1 class name as its parameter.

Comment: Thank you K3v1n for your answer. But not worked :(

Comment: You'll want to check your selector :)